# Java: How to parse through a large number of .csv files?

Tags: java, csv, data-structures

I'm writing a Java program that reads through a folder of .csv files and extracts information from specific columns of the .csv files and puts them all into 1 individual .csv file. The way I'm doing it right now works just fine, however, I have over 100 .csv files I need to extract from, so writing them all out one by one as I do in my main method doesn't seem efficient. I'm not too familiar with data structures, but is there a way I can implement an ArrayList, store all my .csv files into there, and get the same results without having to change my code up too much?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.FileReader;  
import java.io.*;

public class csvParser {

    public static FileWriter createOutputCsvFile(String pathToFile) {

        try {
            FileWriter csvWriter = new FileWriter(pathToFile);
            return csvWriter; 
        }
        
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;  
        }
    }

    // Parses and calculates the source count, destination count and incoming/outgoing packet sizes 
    public static void parseCsvFile(String pathToFile, FileWriter csvWriter) {
       
        try {
            String row;
            int incomingPacketSize = 0;
            int outgoingPacketSize = 0;
            int sourceCount = 0;
            int destinationCount = 0;

            BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToFile));
           
            while ((row = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] line = row.split(",");
                String source = line[2];
                String destination = line[3];
                // remove quotes around the length string
                String length = line[5].replace("\"", "");

                if (source.equals("\"192.168.100.180\"")) {
                    sourceCount++;
                    incomingPacketSize += Integer.parseInt(length);
                }

                if (destination.equals("\"192.168.100.180\"")) {
                    destinationCount++;
                    outgoingPacketSize += Integer.parseInt(length);
                }
            }

            // write to output csv
            writeOutputToCSV(csvWriter, sourceCount, destinationCount, incomingPacketSize, outgoingPacketSize);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());  
        }
    }

    // Write the source count, destination count and incoming/outgoing packet sizes to the output csv file
    public static void writeOutputToCSV(FileWriter csvWriter, int sourceCount, int destinationCount, int incomingPacketSize, int outgoingPacketSize) {

       try {
           csvWriter.append(sourceCount + "," + destinationCount + ","+  incomingPacketSize + "," + outgoingPacketSize + "\n");
           csvWriter.flush();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());  
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    
        FileWriter csvWriter = createOutputCsvFile("/Users/saadkhan/Desktop/Assignment/csv/Outpit.csv");
        
        if (csvWriter == null) {
            System.out.println("Error creating output csv file");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        parseCsvFile("/Users/saadkhan/Desktop/Assignment/csv/1DNSSplit1.csv", csvWriter);
        parseCsvFile("/Users/saadkhan/Desktop/Assignment/csv/1DNSSplit2.csv", csvWriter);
    }
}
```

Comment: This should help: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/337225/parsing-multiple-files-and-their-contents-in-java-using-multithreading-without-e